# spring-boot RabbitListener how can a single queue be bound to a single thread?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

```
@RabbitListener(queues = {"queue1", "queue2"})

public void reciver(String message) {

    logger.info("thread id:{}, message:{}", Thread.currentThread().getId(), message);

}
```

It is found that queue1 and queue2 use the same thread.
Here want to queue1 and queue2 occupy different threads. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two separate listeners to achieve that.

If you set the container `concurrency` to 2, you will get two threads, but the messages from both queues will be distributed across both threads (each queue will not be bound to a particular thread.

The `DirectMessageListenerContainer` (added in version 2.0), uses a different threading model altogether - the listener is invoked on the rabbitmq client library threads; there is no dedicated thread per listener.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer. If I want to use many queue, how to create the RabbitListener?

Comment: When using `@RabbitListener` the only easy way to do that is to create child application contexts - there is much work done by the framework to set up the listener. Or, you can create listener containers yourself, using the legacy listener adapter `MessageListenerAdapter` - but that doesn't have all the features of `@RabbitListener` so it depends on your application if that is an appropriate technique.