# Creating a seperate conatiner per queue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a use case where we have a strict need that all of the queues have a dedicated thread and consumer, which means each thread will only serve one queue.

I have read this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992279/spring-boot-rabbitlistener-how-can-a-single-queue-be-bound-to-a-single-thread/50002914#50002914) and the comment by [Gary Russell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell). He mentioned creating a child application context for having all the features of `@RabbitListener` for achieving what I am trying. Still I didn't get how to do this when the queues are dynamically added during runtime.

If possible please point me to the relevant article for solving this in both the application context way(also how can I create the child contexts) and the `MessageListenerAdapter` way as advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some solution based on Spring Boot and child application context declaration.

1. I have `@RabbitListener` in the component which will be declared in the child context:

   ```
    @EnableRabbit
    public class DynamicRabbitListener {

        @Bean
        public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
        }

        @RabbitListener(queuesToDeclare = @Queue(name = "${dynamic.queue}", autoDelete = "true"))
        public void listen(String payload, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queueName) {
            System.out.printf("Received %s from queue %s%n", payload, queueName);
        }

    }
   ```
2. We need `@EnableRabbit` to register respective annotation processor to the child application context and be able to trigger the proper lifecycle.
3. W need `AmqpAdmin` in this context to be able to declare dynamic queues.
4. Both of those aspects give us some isolation in the processing and logic.
5. Now this is how I declare those contexts:

   ```
    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(ConfigurableApplicationContext parent, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return args -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                String dynamicQueue = "dynamicQueue#" + i;
                AnnotationConfigApplicationContext childApplicationContext =
                        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
                childApplicationContext.setParent(parent);
                childApplicationContext.register(DynamicRabbitListener.class);

                ConfigurableEnvironment environment = parent.getEnvironment();
                MapPropertySource propertySource =
                        new MapPropertySource("dynamic.queues", Map.of("dynamic.queue", dynamicQueue));
                environment.getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
                childApplicationContext.setEnvironment(environment);

                childApplicationContext.refresh();

                rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(dynamicQueue, "test data #" + i);
            }
        };
    }
   ```

Pay attention to the `propertySource` to achieve a dynamic requirements for every child application context with its specific `@RabbitListener`.

The output of my program is like this:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.0)

Received test data #0 from queue dynamicQueue#0
Received test data #1 from queue dynamicQueue#1
Received test data #2 from queue dynamicQueue#2
Received test data #3 from queue dynamicQueue#3
Received test data #4 from queue dynamicQueue#4
Received test data #5 from queue dynamicQueue#5
Received test data #6 from queue dynamicQueue#6
Received test data #7 from queue dynamicQueue#7
Received test data #8 from queue dynamicQueue#8
Received test data #9 from queue dynamicQueue#9
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, How do we get access to all the RabbitListenerEndPointRegistry for those child context.

Comment: `childApplicationContext.refresh();
 RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry = 
 childApplicationContext.getBean(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
 childContextListenerEndpointRegistries.add(registry);` Right now in the parent context I can only think about something like this. Is there any better way ?

Comment: Why do you need that? It might be better to keep those whole `childApplicationContext`s to close them eventually when you it's time to stop the interaction with those queue or so.

Comment: Actually, I have a scheduler, inside which I am fetching the queues from some resource. so need to check if the container is already registered for the queue and only register it if not already registered. I will take your advice for managing those child contexts. I already have an abstraction inside which I am creating these contexts. I can delegate the close operation of these contexts to something like `@PreDestroy` or implement `DisposableBean` in that abstraction and register it as a bean in the parent context. Right now I don't have any other scenarios where I might need to close these.

Comment: Good. I thought that queue is going to be an input for this kind of logic for child application context we have. Therefore it really can be used as a key in a map, and then there is a `computeIfAbsent()` to not create one more context accidentally.